# How to get running sum within condition by postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following table

```
no status amount 
1  2      10000 
2  3      10000
3  2       1000
4  2     -11000
```

I got running some by using following query.

```
SELECT
    main.no
    , main.status
    , main.amount
    , SUM(main.amount) OVER ( 
        ORDER BY
            main.no ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) 
from
    table AS main
```

It returned follows. But I would like to improve my formula by refering to `status` code.

```
no status amount running_sum
1  2      10000  10000
2  3      10000  20000
3  2       1000  21000
4  2     -11000  10000
```

My desired result is following.

I would like to get running sum only in `status = 2` after another status code.

```
no status amount running_sum
1  2      10000  10000
2  3      10000  20000
3  2       1000  11000
4  2     -11000  0
```

How to add conditioning in my formula ?

Are there any good way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: That's what `case` is for. You should fix the example data though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `sum(amount) over(partition by status order by no)`

```
SELECT
    main.no
    , main.status
    , main.amount
    , SUM(main.amount) OVER ( 
        partition by status
        ORDER BY
            main.no ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) as running_sum
from
    mytable AS main
order by no
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/tZYIofUz)

Answer (score 1):

According to your expected output, when `status = 2`, you just need to subtract the running sum of the amount where `status <> 2` from your running sum, try the following:

```
select main.no,
       main.status,
       main.amount,
       sum(main.amount) over (order by main.no) - 
       case when main.status = 2 
         then sum(case when main.status <> 2 then main.amount else 0 end) over (order by main.no) 
         else 0 
       end as running_sum
from table_name as main
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y_EmCQTY)